# PHP : Create some form and submit it with <a href

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Sorry for my spelling...
Im trying to print a list of internets forfeit from my database and then when I click on the hyperlink, it send the id of the forfeit to the page.I have tried to put the id in a hidden value but nothing works, im truck there...

```
    include_once "DataBase/db.php";                 
    if($internet->num_rows != 0){
        while($rows = $internet->fetch_assoc()){
            $nom = $rows["nom"];
            $id = $rows["id"];
            $tech = $rows["technologie"];
            $telechargement = $rows["telechargement"];
            $televersement = $rows["televersement"];
            $utilisation = $rows["utilisation"];
            $prix= $rows["prix"];

            echo '
   <form name="form2" method="POST"     action="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php">
      <div class="boxes">
       <div class="[ price-option price-option--high ]">
        <div class="price-option__detail">
           <span class="price-option__cost">'.$nom.'<br>$'.$prix.'</span>
            </div>
            **<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'"></input>
              <a href="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php" onclick="document.forms["form2"].submit(); class="price-option__purchase">Voir</a>** 
                </div>
                </div>
            </form>';
        }
}
```

then on the second page, i would take the forfeit id to get the rest of data...
if its not clear, you guys can see what im talking about here : http://fournisseursquebec.com/Forfaits.php
then select internet...
Thank you !

Comment: Can you not just use css to style a submit button to look the same as the `<a>` link you are using now? That way you can submit the form normally without the use of javascript. Also you don't need to close the input using `</input>` just add `/>` at the end of the open `<input>` tag.

Comment: Also, your `onclick` inline javascript does not have a close quote

Comment: Lastly, this portion `document.forms["form2"]` of the inline js will conflict with your `onclick="`. You need to escape those.

Comment: If i cant do it the the hyperlink, ill have no cloice to do it with the button... But still, i think the button submit an other form then the one i put there...maybe there is an other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just turn the link into a button and submit normally. It's possible that you are running into malformation of your html by the way you have concatenated your string in PHP. You would need to do some escaping in your scenario. This is what you have:

```
<!--                                                  wrong--v-----v missing---v                   -->
<a href="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php" onclick="document.forms["form2"].submit(); class="price-option__purchase">Voir</a>
```

Just change it to a button or submit and style it that way:

```
include_once("DataBase/db.php");                 
if($internet->num_rows != 0){
    while($rows = $internet->fetch_assoc()){
        $nom = $rows["nom"];
        $id = $rows["id"];
        $tech = $rows["technologie"];
        $telechargement = $rows["telechargement"];
        $televersement = $rows["televersement"];
        $utilisation = $rows["utilisation"];
        $prix= $rows["prix"];
?>
<form name="form2" method="POST" action="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="[ price-option price-option--high ]">
            <div class="price-option__detail">
               <span class="price-option__cost"><?php echo $nom; ?><br>$<?php echo $prix; ?></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_id" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
            **<div class="price-option__purchase">
                <input type="submit" value="Voir" />
            </div>**
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    }
}
```

Apply your css to the submit button.

```
price-option__purchase input {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , this has worked, but still i have found a way to submit the form with a href so it looks like i want! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the best solve but you could use a session for this.
Place this inside of your while loop.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
?>
```

On your second form just do the same but reverse it.

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Comment: i cant use this because the $id change with every forfeit... i need to do like <a href="Fournisseurs/Videotron.php" onclick="<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>"  >                                                                                                             So if i click on the link, then the $id is set...